# Opencv unable to draw lines on image

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to draw some shapes in opencv c++

I first extract a bounding box then draw a line in that box. My expecatation is that this line will be reflected in the original image.

My code is like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void draw(Mat& frame){
 auto best_viola_jones = frame.clone();


    auto violaJonesDetections = get_detections();

           for (auto &rect: violaJonesDetections) {
        auto clone = best_viola_jones(rect);

        auto circles = get_circles();
        auto lines = get_lines();

        if (dartboardDetected(circles, lines, rect)) {
            counter += 1;
            cout << "detected" << endl;

            rectangle(clone, Point(rect.x, rect.y),
                      Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                      Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);


        }

    }

    cout << "Total dartboards detected: " << counter;


    imwrite("result/best_viola_jones.jpg", best_viola_jones);
}
```

It is detecting my object but not drawing anything out.

I have banged my head against the wall to solve this. Could someone offer some guidance?

Comment: it seems that you're drawing on the sub-image, but the coordinates of the rectangle refer to the whole image. If so, you're drawing, but outside your sub-image

Answer (score 0):

`I don't have the reputation to comment, but I have clarifying questions/comments:

You mention drawing a line, but it seems that you are drawing a rectangle:

```
rectangle(clone, Point(rect.x, rect.y),
                      Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                      Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
```

Then, you are extracting a bounding box

```
 auto clone = best_viola_jones(rect);
```

Here, I think that Rect is a Rect2d, it is not declared.

Then, you are drawing using the `rect` coordinates.  It may be that `Point(rect.x, rect.y)` is larger than clone's height and width.

If you output the size of clone and the coordinates you are trying to write on it, I think that this would be helpful debugging.  And perhaps you need to write the `circles` and `lines` variables instead of `rect`.